# What is a geocentric altitude?

Tags: astronomy, terminology

In NAO TN no.69, Yallop defines

> *ARCV as geocentric difference in altitude between the centre of the Sun and the centre of the Moon for a given latitude and longitude, ignoring the effects of refraction.*

As far as I know, altitude is a topocentric coordinate and can't see how one could define a geocentric altitude. So what is a "geocentric difference in altitude?"

Answer (score 1):

ARCV is an abbreviation of *arc of vision* and it is an angle not a height in units of length.

Suppose you're standing looking at the horizon, and for the sake of argument we'll say it's nighttime and the Moon is above the horizon while the Sun is below the horizon:

[image: ARCV]

The arc of vision is the angle subtended by the vertical dashed line from the centre of the Earth. So it is related to the angular altitude, which is what I assume Yallop means by *altitude*.

If anyone is intersed, [the note is available here](http://www.icoproject.org/pdf/yallop_1997.pdf).

**Response to comment:**

The horizon just sets the orientation relative to which you're measuring the angle. If you take the side view of the above diagram it would look like:

[image: ARCV side view]

Bear in mind the size of the Earth is greatly exaggerated in the diagram and in practice there is a tiny difference in the ARCV you'd measure from the centre of the Earth compared to using yourself as the reference point.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRennie. But I think you misunderstood my question. I know this is not the altitude as used by airplanes. What I have problem is with what he means by "geocentric difference in altitude." I mean how will you define a horizon while standing at center of the Earth

Comment: @Nabigh: aha, I see what you mean. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks much clearer now. Isn't this equivalent to finding the difference in the declinations of Sun and Moon?

Comment: @Nabigh: no, because the declination is always measured relative to the North celestial pole. The point about ARCV is that it's always measured relative to the observer. In effect it's the difference in the declinations if we redefine the coordinates so the observer is standing at the North pole.

Comment: isn't declination measured from the celestial equator? I think you are referring to co-latitude. So if I just find the difference in altitudes of Sun and Moon I'll get the ARCV he's talking about right.